# How does firebase Crashlytics limit key/value pairs for an Exception?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

So the [crashlytics docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android) have following warning about "key-value pair" logging:

> Crashlytics supports a **maximum** of **64 key/value pairs**. After you reach this threshold, additional values are **not saved**. Each key/value pair can be up to 1 kB in size.

But I am a bit confused about how it actually works. So I have following questions:

PS: k/v pairs -> key-value pairs :P

1. Let's say I have a bunch of k/v pairs, and I log an Exception, are k/v pairs reset and I have another limit of 64 k/v pairs?
2. If it is not reset and I already have 64 custom keys, how do I clear the old keys to make space for newer ones? **Am I stuck with these 64 custom keys forever?**
3. If I want to have a few unique permanent k/v pairs for user properties and app state and I want other temporary properties which are, let's say, activity specific for debugging exceptions (just an example, I know we can use logs), then how do I do that.?

Answer (score 0):

1) For keys:
- Keys are set on each launch of the app or if the same key gets a new value to replace the existing key's value. For example, if you had a key set to capture the current game level - you may change the value of that key without creating a new key. 
- They are reset on each app launch.
-  Keys don't include a timestamp (they're more intended to capture a state of an app, rather then function as breadcrumbs)
- You didn't ask, but there is a maximum of 64 keys with each key/value pair maxed at 1 KB.

2) For logs:
- There is a maximum size of 64 KB. 
- We using a rolling log, FIFO. 
- Also reset when the app is launched.

Comment: First of all if you even read the question, I already quoted the 64key 1KB limit in the second line. Secondly can you be clear what you mean by "app launch", do you mean the creation of application process.? And do you mean it clears the k/v pairs at each app launch and then we can have a fresh new set of 64 k/v pairs even if the old 64 keys are totally different.?